# Access current component data from within slot template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-slots

I have the following vue component

```html
<template>
   <CardGroup>
      <template #headerRight>
         <div>Total items: {{ this.total }}</div>
      </template>
   </CardGroup>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         total: 0
      };
   }
}
```

I don't understand the scoping problem. The `this` in the slot template is `null` and I cannot access the `this.total` data property. I can use that property outside the slot template though.
Why `this` is null inside the slot template?

Comment: Hey, using ```this``` in template isn't required. You can easily call ```total``` into your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue binds properties automatically, please go through it.
[data binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

```
<div>Total items: {{ total }}</div>
```

Comment: Yes i just found it seconds after i posted the quesion. It's a bit confusing though, and implicit. In the methods you use "this" but in the template you don't use it. A bit confusing. I still don't understand how people find vue easier than react! lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was somewhat simple. I just had to omit `this`

```
<div>Total items: {{ total }}</div>
```

It turns out vue binds properties automatically to the _vm.